# Which loop is better?

Tags: c

Am a beginner at C here; Would like to ask which of the following 2 code is better for printing odd integers between 1 and *given number*?

```
// Precond: n > 0
void print_odd_integers(int n)  {
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i+=2)
        printf("%d ", i);
    printf("\n");
}

// Precond: n > 0
void print_odd_integers(int n)  {
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
        if (i%2 != 0)
            printf("%d ", i);
    printf("\n");
}
```

If neither can be said to be clearly "better", what are the different trade-offs between the versions?

Comment: Better in what sense?

Comment: I was literally asked "which one's better", with no specificity on what basis or what terms - sorry about that!

Comment: @BrianLee I took the liberty of editing the question a bit, so it doesn't get closed as "Primarily opinion based". Feel free to roll-back if you disagree with my edit.

Comment: You can answer the question easily yourself just by dumping the *assembly* generated by each loop and comparing. With gcc, just add `#include <stdio.h>` at the top, add a `1` and `2` to the end of the function names, save it as `loop.c` and then `gcc -S -masm=intel -o loops.asm loops.c` (you can add varying levels of optimization to inspect the differences if your curious). You will find loop 1 wins just on the instruction and branch count alone.

Comment: Which do you find easier to read?

Comment: @hyde Sure, thank you! :) Shall better phrase my questions next time!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks a lot there! I've just started out so didn't know how to self-answer that - I'll try that out! :)

Comment: `if ( ( i & 1 ) != 0 )` is faster and better than `i % 2`, however method 1 is better.

Answer (score 3):

Use the **First Loop** if `n` is not the extreme case like `INT_MAX` and also when `i` starts from an odd integer, Since it already skips half the number iterations.

Else use the **Second Loop** because the first will become infinite loop if `n = INT_MAX`.

Comment: Doesn't the second loop *potentially* execute infinitely as well when `n = INT_MAX`? Anyway, it's [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376682/is-int-max1-int-min-in-signed-integer) in both versions of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely the first one. 
Reasons: 

- less lines of code

- branching statements (if, if else, switch cases, ...) are mainly avoided if there is other ways of handling the situation.

- time complexity of both algorithms are the same O(n). So this is mainly a matter of which code is more beatifull. And always remember, a code that is more readable is prettier.

**EDIT**

- the fact that on the edge the first solution has undefined behavior is obvious. but these input validations must be checked outside the algorithm part. and it's much recommended that you DO NOT mix validation codes with your logic. easily you can check for `i` at first of the function and print `INT_MAX` if `i==INT_MAX-1` or `i==INT_MAX`

Comment: - no division (mod) operation `i%2`

Comment: @i486 if you like, suggest edit, i accept, tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally, they are the same, so it really doesn't matter all that much unless you really need max performance.

However, the solution where you skip the `if` statement would be a lot efficient. You're skipping half the numbers and don't need to check a condition with modulus.

Comment: They are not functionally the same. The first exhibits undefined behavior when n=INT_MAX-1.

Comment: @PaulHankin How are they different functionally? It looks like to me that they would print the exact same thing.

Comment: @EmptyArsenal If `n = INT_MAX-1` then what is `n+2`? Undefined behavior.

Comment: Either way, you have a problem once you get to the max int because he's using `<=`, which will always be true when `n == INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

Both loops have undefined behavior if `n == INT_MAX` because of arithmetic overflow.

- The first loop will potentially give you *better* performance
- The second loop is potentially more readable (for a beginner) and less error prone if you later change the code to start from an arbitrary value.

  I would use braces around the `for` body as it is not a simple one line statement and spaces around binary operators to improve readability:

  ```
  void print_odd_integers(int n)  {
      int i;
      for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
          if (i % 2 != 0)
              printf("%d ", i);
      }
      printf("\n");
  }
  ```

Note also that both loops will output a space after the last number before the newline, which may be incorrect.

You can address both issues with one extra test:

```
void print_odd_integers(int n)  {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += 2) {
        printf("%d", i);
        if (i == n)
           break;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I would instead `void printOdd(int i)
{
 unsigned counter = 0;
 unsigned number;

 while ((number = ((counter++ << 1) + 1)) < i)
 {
  printf("%d ", number);
 }
}`

Comment: @Peter_J: your interesting proposal implements different semantics from the OP's code (the end value should be included) and it would not fix the `INT_MAX` problem on architectures where `INT_MAX == UINT_MAX` ;-)

Comment: `INT_MAX == UINT_MAX` any example please (a not the one's complement numbers as those machines do not exist any more 0 except some eccentric back compatible univac compatibitily modes. BTW I believe that C compiler was never implemented for that architecture)

Comment: I did not imply that such architectures existed, both *would* and the smiley account for that. The prototype DS9K I'm working on will have a  compliant C compiler and the proposed approach, with `<` changed into `<=` for consistency with the OP's requirements, you would have an infinite loop, which is arguably better than undefined behavior.

Comment: DS9K - For this example I always say: as the death machine it will blow itself up before any program execution :). I am not the theoretician and IT is the practical science. If I have ever to program the **real** machine with this constraints I will take the adequate steps to avoid the UBs

Comment: @Peter_J: I quite agree! being a pragmatic programmer too. Yet there are simpler and more readable alternatives for the `INT_MAX` issue, as posted.

Answer (score -3):

The second solution is the "professional" way.

One thing you could change would be the Layout:

```
void print_odd_integers(int n)  
{
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        if (i%2 != 0)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
         }
    }
    printf("End.\n");
    system("Pause"); //So you can see what you did :)
}
```

Have fun :)!

Comment: *The second solution is the "professional" way.* not really,  Furthermore, your layout is broken and `system("Pause\n");` is completely unprofessional.

Comment: Layout is still broken... did you down vote me?

Comment: Broken? 

I think in this basic program it's okay to use "system("pause")"...

The NASA will probably check the code before they use it to fly to Mars :D

Comment: `system("Pause");` is a window specific trick to prevent the automatic closing of the shell window when a non-GUI program is run. Running the program at the command prompt in an existing shell window precludes the need for such a workaround. The layout is still broken because the `}` is misaligned. No big deal, but since it is the only change from the OP's code, it ought to be consistent for example's sake.